# Does spring mbean and mbean received with jconsole are different?

Tags: java, spring, jmx, jconsole

I have application created with Spring and has access through jmx to set some parameters. The problem that when I access by jconsole - all works, when access from my graphic interface - doesn't work. In debugger I checked that invoked the same method with the same parameters. Does it possible that Spring privides different instance of bean that I receive from jconsole?
Thanks.

Comment: It's better if you show what you're doing in your "graphic interface" (what is it?).

Comment: I have set field to MBean in class of graphic interface by Spring

Comment: "works" and "doesn't work" mean nothing ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instance is the same (unless your bean is prototype-scoped)

You can verify that by printing the object's `toString()` to the console and compare the values after `@`.